# Replacing ALL occurrences of an array's elements

Tags: jquery, replace

Here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GUWkN/).

The problem is, the replacement is done correctly only on the first matched html element, and for the rest matched elements, it only copies the text from the first one.

I believe that the problem is with `html()`, as it only `Gets the HTML contents of the first element in the set of matched elements`, as stated in the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/html/).

How should I correct the code, so that it does the replacement in ALL of the macthed elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to loop over each element, and within that loop go through the `replacers` on the content of the current elemtn

```
 /* loop all elements*/
 $("div").html(function (i, oldHtml) {
    /* now loop replacemts on this element*/
    for (var key in replacers) {
        oldHtml = oldHtml.replace(replacers[key], key);
    }
    return oldHtml
})
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GUWkN/4/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using a counter (`i`) to keep track of the iteration, at the simplest:

```
var replacers = {
    'a': /1/gi,
    'b': /2/gi,
    'c': /3/gi
};

var el = $("div"),
    i = 0;

for (var key in replacers) {
    $('div').eq(i).html(function(_,h){
        return h.replace(replacers[key], key);
    });
    i++;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/GUWkN/2/).

This may, however, be a little naive for your use-case outside of a simplified demo.

Comment: was thinking that looping elements once, then looping the regex object to only replace elemnt html once would be faster than replacing html for each property of regex object... jsperf proved me very wrong...by very significant difference....any insight as to why?  http://jsperf.com/multiple-regex-on-multiple-elements

Answer (score 1):

I think you are not doing what you want. In your example you are:

el will point to all divs now:

```
var el = $("div");
```

now you are saving the content of the first element to var html

```
html = el.html();

for (var key in replacers) {
```

In the loop you replace the content of the var html (where you saved `'111'`) prior with `'aaa'` in the first run. the secound and third literation of the loop don't do anything, because html contains `'aaa'` now

```
    html = html.replace(replacers[key], key);
}
```

And at last, you set every div to `'aaa'`

```
el.html(html);
```

here another, hopefully "straight forward" example of how you could do it:

```
var i = 1;
var modified_html;
for (var key in replacers) {
    modified_html=$('div:nth-child(' + i + ')').html().replace(replacers[key], key);
    $('div:nth-child(' + i + ')').html(modified_html)
    i++;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JtMAj/

I hope I could help :)